# My first complex SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been writing a C# program to create a database in SQL Server from imported .csv data files. I've now got the database working and need to make some fairly complex (for me) queries to it. For the problem that I'm currently working on I have these queries:

```
SELECT MatchID, DateTimeKO = DateKickOff + CAST(TimeKickOff AS DATETIME)
FROM Match
WHERE MatchID = 9000
```

which returns:

```
MatchID DateTimeKO
9000    2011-09-17 14:00:00.000
```

and:

```
(SELECT MatchID, OddsFirstTimeTaken AS WhenOddsTaken, MarketName, Outcome, Odds, NumberOfBets, VolumeMatched,InPlay
FROM Data as D
WHERE MatchID = 9000  AND MarketName = 'Match Odds' AND Outcome = 'The Draw'
UNION --ALL
SELECT MatchID, OddsLastTimeTaken AS WhenOddsTaken, MarketName, Outcome, Odds, NumberOfBets, VolumeMatched,InPlay
FROM Data as D
WHERE MatchID = 9000 AND MarketName = 'Match Odds' AND Outcome = 'The Draw'
)ORDER BY WhenOddsTaken
```

which returns:

```
MatchID WhenOddsTaken           MarketName  Outcome     Odds    NumberOfBets    VolumeMatched   InPlay
9000    2011-09-17 13:58:17.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.80    243             15997.30        0
9000    2011-09-17 13:59:14.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.90    39              1923.44         0
9000    2011-09-17 13:59:31.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.95    8               209.12          0
9000    2011-09-17 13:59:44.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.85    106             5740.90         0
9000    2011-09-17 14:00:17.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.90    33              628.26          1
9000    2011-09-17 14:00:24.000 Match Odds  The Draw    4.10    2               2.70            1
9000    2011-09-17 14:00:29.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.85    53              693.46          1
9000    2011-09-17 14:01:02.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.95    2               94.28           1
9000    2011-09-17 14:01:24.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.80    69              3988.24         1
9000    2011-09-17 14:04:05.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.90    33              628.26          1
9000    2011-09-17 14:05:22.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.75    20              1873.80         1
```

What I would now like to do is add another where condition that returns the data from the 2nd query, only if the 'WhenOddsTaken' datetime is greater than the value of 'DateTimeKO' in the first query. i.e. it should return:

```
MatchID WhenOddsTaken           MarketName  Outcome     Odds    NumberOfBets    VolumeMatched   InPlay
9000    2011-09-17 14:00:17.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.90    33              628.26          1
9000    2011-09-17 14:00:24.000 Match Odds  The Draw    4.10    2               2.70            1
9000    2011-09-17 14:00:29.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.85    53              693.46          1
9000    2011-09-17 14:01:02.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.95    2               94.28           1
9000    2011-09-17 14:01:24.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.80    69              3988.24         1
9000    2011-09-17 14:04:05.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.90    33              628.26          1
9000    2011-09-17 14:05:22.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.75    20              1873.80         1
```

Additionally to this I would like a further query to return the first line of data that occurs for a certain time after DateTimeKO, e.g. DateTimeKO plus 2 minutes (first line after 2011-09-17 14:02:00.000) would return:

```
MatchID WhenOddsTaken           MarketName  Outcome     Odds    NumberOfBets    VolumeMatched   InPlay
9000    2011-09-17 14:04:05.000 Match Odds  The Draw    3.90    33              628.26          1
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: @MatBailie they're not identical :) `OddsFirstTimeTaken` vs `OddsLastTimeTaken`. but yes, they're the same otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have data to run it, but something along these lines:

```
with x as (
    SELECT MatchID, DateTimeKO = DateKickOff + CAST(TimeKickOff AS DATETIME)
    FROM Match
    WHERE MatchID = 9000
),
y as (
    SELECT MatchID, OddsFirstTimeTaken AS WhenOddsTaken, MarketName, Outcome, Odds, NumberOfBets, VolumeMatched,InPlay
    FROM Data as D
    WHERE MatchID = 9000  AND MarketName = 'Match Odds' AND Outcome = 'The Draw'
    UNION --ALL
    SELECT MatchID, OddsLastTimeTaken AS WhenOddsTaken, MarketName, Outcome, Odds, NumberOfBets, VolumeMatched,InPlay
    FROM Data as D
    WHERE MatchID = 9000 AND MarketName = 'Match Odds' AND Outcome = 'The Draw'
)
select top (1) y.MatchID, WhenOddsTaken, MarketName, Outcome, Odds, NumberOfBets, VolumeMatched, InPlay
from y
inner join x on y.MatchID = x.MatchID
where WhenOddsTaken > dateadd(minute, 2, DateTimeKO)
order by WhenOddsTaken asc
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Just needed to change 'select top (1) *' to 'select y.MatchID, WhenOddsTaken, MarketName, Outcome, Odds, NumberOfBets, VolumeMatched,InPlay' to answer my first question. Putting top (1) back in gives me part of my second question but can you tell me how I can add 2 minutes to DateTimeKO in the WHERE clause in your 2nd from last line of code? i.e. where WhenOddsTaken > (DateTimeKO + 2mins)

Comment: The answer above gives the correct result for my last question. Removing top (1) and the final WHERE clause answers the first part of my question. Thanks

Comment: Hi dean. As an extension to this problem I would now like to remove the 'WHERE MatchID = 9000' conditions and return the top (1) row for each individual MatchID present in the database. If you know how to achieve this, please could you submit another answer for this. Thanks

Comment: Sure. Could I ask you for some more sample data, with various MatchIDs?

Comment: Hi. I added it as a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344534/complex-sql-server-query-extension-to-previous-post